# change a date value depending on a bool

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

**What I want**

I have a model/store/form combination boiling down to:

```
Field Name  Type  UI Control
isAllDay    bool  Checkbox
startDate   date  DateField
endDate     date  DateField
startTime   date  TimeField
endTime     date  TimeField
```

If `isAllDay` is checked, I set both TimeFields to midnight.

But furthermore, I have to get the endDate field to show one day earlier; because "from Tue to Tue" means "the 24 hours between Tue midnight and Wed midnight" and "from Mon to Fri" means "between Mon midnight and Sat midnight".

So, isAllDay from Tue 09/30/14 to Tue 09/30/14 should be submitted as from 2014-09-30 0:00 to 2014-10-01 0:00.

**What I did**

I tried to build `convert()` and `serialize()` functions into the the model:

```
dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
name: 'endDate',
type: 'date'
...
name:'isAllDay',
type:'boolean',
convert:function(v, rec) {
    if(v==true) {
        rec.set("endDate",Ext.Date.add(rec.get("endDate"),Ext.Date.DAY,-1));
    }
    return v;
},
serialize:function(v, rec) {
    if(v==true) {
        rec.set("endDate",Ext.Date.add(rec.get("endDate"),Ext.Date.DAY,1));
    }
    return v;
}
```

The convert function works like a charm; it even seems to work TOO good, the serialize function doesn't work at all.

- I am sent `isAllDay:true, startDate:2014-10-02, endDate:2014-10-03`
- convert makes that `isAllDay:true, startDate:2014-10-02, endDate:2014-10-02`, which I see in the form
- I don't change the values in the form
- the record in the store is updated from the form
- now the record contains `isAllDay:true, startDate:2014-10-02, endDate:2014-10-01`!
- then the store is synced, sending 2014-10-01 to the server

What exactly is going wrong here? Why isn't "serialize" called, but "convert" is, obviously, called twice?

EDIT: I made a fiddle that shows the problem, thanks to existdissolve for his help: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/b8c

Comment: Do you have an example? When I try what you've described, it seems to work as you want. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/b88

Comment: Had to add a tag :( But good to know that it works in ExtJS 5 without hassle. I bookmarked that fiddle for further reference after we switched to ExtJS 5 somewhere in the future.

Comment: I forked your fiddle into a new one compatible with Ext4 and doing what I did - and of course the error is available there: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/b8c